# AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth equivalent for iOS15 UIButton

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I'm using UIKit, not SwiftUI. Previously, I used setAttributedTitle and I also set AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to true, and the font size shrinks to match the button width. I can't seem to match this behavior with the new button configurations and swift's AttributedString.

Here's what I have:

```
var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
config.imagePadding = 5
config.imagePlacement = .trailing
config.image = UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis.circle",
     withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .medium))
config.titlePadding = 10
config.cornerStyle = .capsule
let handler: UIButton.ConfigurationUpdateHandler = { button in
     button.configuration?.background.backgroundColor = Colors.specLabel
     button.configuration?.baseForegroundColor = Colors.greyText
}
myButton.configuration = config
myButton.configurationUpdateHandler = handler
```

And then

```
guard let attributedString = try? AttributedString(markdown: "hello **hello** hello") else { return }
myButton.configuration?.attributedTitle = attributedString
```

Every time, I get a multi-line button. Setting numberOfLines, lineBreakMode and adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is all ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe you can set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` on a button using `UIButton.Configuration`

Comment: You can use the `titleTextAttributesTransformer` and calculate desired font size. Unfortunately you have to do various manual calculations using api such as `NSString.boundingRect(with:options:attributes:context)` and `UIView. sizeThatFits`.